# jQuery animate background position in chunks?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to use jQuery to make a background position of my span go down 10 pixels every second. What is a good way to do this?

I've been playing with jQuery animate, delay, CSS, and some `setTimeout` functions but I can't get anything to work. Suggestions greatly appriciated!

I'm trying to make my y-position go from 0 to 100 in increments of 10 pixels, and then stop the animation.

Comment: Can you share the latest state of your experiments so that we can point out what's wrong with your approach/implementation?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can't animate background position properly because of the need to animate two values instead of just one. Explanation and solution here:

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/