# How to animate background position in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem in IE8 with an animation effect. The code works in firefox, safari, chrome... but no in IE8.

[The demo is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/wpzT6/)

The code I'm using is:

```
$(function(){
    $("#wrapper").animate({
        backgroundPosition: "-261px center"         
    }, 12000 );
});
```

I'm using jquery-1.4.3.min.js

Is there a way to make it work in IE8?

## --- UPDATE ---

i've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/wpzT6/) and now it works¿?¿?¿ I havent changed nothing.Just copied the fiddle source frame and saved as index3.html and works.

I don't understand nothing, but its working! Can anyone explain that?

You can see the result here: dev.thepixellary.es/index3.html

## --- UPDATE 2 ---

it works because in fiddle i was using jquery 1.3.2 instead of 1.5.2 but then this code  dont work(IE8):

```
$(".menu li").each(function(idx) {
  $(this).delay(idx * 1000).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

jsfiddle.net/oterox/wpzT6/8/

Comment: This works even in IE6: [link](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/). Maybe helps You.

Comment: It must be the 'center' attribute which make IE to failed. Now that you have a static value (20px), IE could do it

Comment: No. In the fiddle i'm using jquery 1.3.2 instead of 1.5.2 and that works but.... then my other jquery fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating background-position is [technically unsupported](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7951) by jQuery.

Use the [jQuery BackgroundPosition](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect) plugin to fix this issue.

Comment: i'm using that plugin but still doesn't work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/wpzT6/8/)

Comment: I have gotten this plugin to work before.  Your fiddle has fizzled (404).  What is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a undefined beahviour for all browsers. If it works in some browser, it is by luke.

[See the doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value.

You have to use this plugin : [Background-position animations](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect)

Some duplicates:

- [jQuery animate background position in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404332/jquery-animate-background-position-in-chunks)
- [jquery animate background position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position)

Comment: with that plugin i still get the same error.Do i have to add only jquery.backgroundPosition.js for the code to work? I've modified it in the demo but still dont works.

Comment: Try to replace the center part of the animation : backgroundPosition: "-261px 20px"

Answer (score 0):

Working in IE8 !!

you can see the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/mnjZZ/)

I've replaced my code with this one:

```
$.fn.scrollingBackground = function(options) {

   // settings and defaults.
    var settings = options || {};
    var duration = settings.duration|| 1;
    var step = settings.step || 1;

    var element = this;

    var animate = function() {
        element.css("background-position", "0px 0px");
        element.animate({
            backgroundPosition: step + "px 0px"
        }, duration);            
    };
    animate();
};
```

and i'm using the *jQuery BackgroundPosition* plugin

thk all.