# jQuery animate background-position, not working in ie

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I am having a small jQuery animate function, which is working in all browsers except IE. Here my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bgHover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{width:54px; height:54px;}
.bgHover{background: url("../images/shine.png") no-repeat scroll -150px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width:54px; height:54px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 8px;}
.bg{background-color:black; width:54px; height:54px;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var $e = $(".container")
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                $e.find(".bgHover").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 0},500,function(){
                    $e.find(".bgHover").css("background-position","-99px 0"); 
                    $e.find(".bgHover").animate({backgroundPosition: '99px 0'});
                });
            },2500);
        });
```

Please find the above code which is working in all Browsers except IE.

Comment: keep in mind that, IE < 9 wont support Background position.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Is there any solution?

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993922/how-to-animate-background-position-in-ie8

Comment: what IE version ? because your code works on ie 9 and 10

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: yes, it is not working in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
    css({
        "background-position-x" : "-99px",
        "background-position-y" : "0"

    );
```

But rmbr in IE8 and before that, you need to use some other scripts, I'm looking for it

**EDIT:**

I belive that will help you https://github.com/kbwood/backgroundpos

Comment: Dziewonski: Please share scripts, if any.