# HTML 5 / CSS animation - Scrolling tiled background image

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I have seen some examples of tween animation in html, but cannot seem to find a clear answer that fits my exact need.

I am trying to make a div of a certain width that takes up 100% webpage height. This div should have a tiled background image on it.

Here is the tricky part -- I want the tiled images to scroll vertically at a settable speed within the div.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not the best question, but [here is an example anyway](https://jsbin.com/zidecob/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: How would you improve this question. The linked webpage seems to apply more to a problem in need of a solution not identifying algorithms or design methods

Comment: @Exitcode0 Actually, identifying algorithms or design methods is not what StackOverflow is for. It's purely a problem-solving website.

Comment: Ok, sorry for posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by animating the `background-position` property.

```css
body{
    background: url("https://www.google.be/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") repeat;
    -webkit-animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
    animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scrolling {
  from{
      background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to{
      background-position: 0 105%;
  }
}
```

Comment: [No need for those prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation). The only prefix that *might* be needed is `-webkit-`.

Comment: This only seems to work in Chrome and not in IE or Firefox. Also, there is a slight jump when it restarts

Comment: @Exitcode0 Take a look at these 3 questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095686/jquery-animate-background-position-not-working-in-ie) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449474/animate-background-position-y-in-firefox-with-jquery) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340130/jquery-animate-background-image-on-y-axis). You should be able to solve the rest of your issues now by searching a bit.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found a better example
http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/Hyg3C/20/

Comment: @Exitcode0 Do you understand the example, or are you just blindly copying the code?

Comment: @Exitcode0 What poor design? Also, I'm asking because the example you linked is not really "better". It's using the same principle, but with a lot more unnecessary code. StackOverflow is not really fond of people that just come here, ask for "gimme the code plz" and copy everything blindly without knowing what it does. We rather help you learn how it works. So that next time you can think of the solution yourself instead of having to ask again.

Comment: @Exitcode0 Not trying to shame you, more trying to discourage you from randomly copy-pasting code. Learning to understand new things will give a better outcome for both parties involved. I fixed the animation skip by playing around with the animation values (105% now instead of 100%).